# iOS tableView not showing full table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

My problem is here I've a table view, with `carbonKit` framework but the buttons in the bottom are drawn over the last portion of the tableView, like this

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

As you can see, the last row in under the bottom view, only in iPads, iPhones look correctly. Any ideas how to solve it?

**EDIT:**

iPhone screen:

[image: iPhone correct]

Comment: Can you add a picture from an iPhone -- working properly -- to illustrate what's wrong?  Having a hard time understanding the problem with the image in the OP

Comment: Don't worry I fixed it with a footer height (y)